# Insert element as sibling using D3js

Tags: d3.js

I have an html structure like this

```
<div>
    <div><span id="span1">Test 1</span></div>
    <div><span id="span2">Test 2</span></div>
    <div><span id="span3">Test 3</span></div>
    <div><span id="span4">Test 4</span></div>
</div>
```

I have to insert an svg element, using jQuery I can easily do it like

```
for(var i in arr)
    $('.span' + i).parent().append('<svg />')
```

How can I acheive the same using D3.js? as d`3.select('.span' + i).parent` is giving error `parent is not a function`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var pnode = d3.select('.span' + i).node().parentNode
```

d3.select returns a selection, use node() to return the actual dom node, and then parentNode to get the parent

You'll then have to re-select that parent node in another d3 selection to do d3 things to it

```
d3.select(pnode)
```

PS. For your example above it'll need to be '#span' to select the nodes by id, not '.span' (and it'd probably be better to selectAll the nodes at once and then .each the result rather than a loop) but I think that's the parent thing covered